# Automatically pause print jobs on server 2008r2

Tags: windows-server-2008, printing

Is there an easy (and bonus: free?) way to have a printer hosted on server2008r2 automatically pause any print job that comes to it?

I've searched for an answer for this, but all my search results are threads from people trying to fix paused jobs that they don't want to be paused.

Currently we use PCounter to do far less than PCounter is designed to do.  We don't use it to track account balances or anything like that any more.  Its only function these days is to pause the jobs coming into a printer so users have to walk up to a station and ask them to send the job through (thus catching the accidental 80 page print jobs).

Basically, is there another way to do this than to keep paying for PCounter?

Edits for additional info:
The printer in question is a Konica Minolta Bizhub c360.  The setting is a high school library, student use printer.

Comment: Some printers allow you to print to a users queue, that user has to then go to the printer and enter a pin for it to print. (I'm not suggesting going out and buying a new printer) but maybe yours already has this unused feature?

Comment: `Its only function these days is to pause the jobs coming into a printer so users have to walk up to a station and ask them to send the job through` - By that do you mean they have to walk up to a person, who then releases the print job?

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes, that's correct.

Comment: @Drifter104 I believe our printer (Konica Minolta Bizhub c360) does have that capability, but as this is in a school library setting, we would have to enter and manage 1600+ account codes in a single device to make that work.

Comment: Well then you could probably simply pause each of the printers on the print server and give this person access to the Print Management console on the server in order to unpause them as needed.

Comment: Interesting thought, it looks like setting the printer to Paused in print management will hold all jobs like we want, BUT you can't selectively print individual jobs, like my users are used to doing.  Unpausing the whole queue causes all jobs to be printed immediately.

Comment: It actually is possible... with a little bit of work. Granted I wouldn't want to be the one having to do this but if your goal is to eliminate the financial cost of the third party software then you can achieve that with a little bit of time and effort cost. How many users and how many print jobs in a typical day?